# Docker pull from Private Registry gives Local error : tls : bad record MAC

Tags: docker

I have installed docker on my virtual machine Ubuntu 18.04 by following https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#uninstall-docker-engine . However I am not able to pull images from my private registry , I get the following error

```
e7c96db7181b: Pull complete 
f910a506b6cb: Pull complete 
c2274a1a0e27: Downloading  57.24MB/57.24MB
c8e2e3215e55: Download complete 
660134a4005d: Downloading  9.582MB/9.582MB
local error: tls: bad record MAC
```

Can someone please help me here. I am not able to find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Check your network. It's because of a slow network or poor connectivity issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm what *Sridharan D* said in the previous answer.

I was having the same issue and the most common explanation online was that the issue may be related to the connection/internet adapter quality and stability.

There are some possible solutions:

1. Close every application that may be using your internet connection. In my situation turning off WhatsApp desktop helped a lot (I was far from my AP and my wireless device was quite cheap).
2. Connect to a different access point or connection: if you have a repeater, you may try connecting directly to your router (this as well helped a lot in my case). If you are connected to a 5ghz network, try connecting to 2.4ghz.
3. Try a different device: different WiFi adapter, direct cable connection.
4. Restart the router.